# Android MediaPlayer takes a long time to start playing an .ogg file while .m4a works fine

Tags: android

I'm simply playing an .ogg file like this:

```kotlin
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(ctx, Uri.fromFile(File(cacheDir, "audio.ogg")));
mediaPlayer!!.start()
```

The `create()` call takes 13 seconds to return.

The .ogg file is 146 MB in size.

If I encode the same audio as an .m4a file I end up with a 169 MB file and if I play that with MediaPlayer, it loads pretty much instantly (about 200 ms).

What's going on?